# Will Chrome add-ons be fully compatible with Firefox Web Extensions platform?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm wondering whether Chrome add-ons will be compatible with Firefox Web Extensions platform or not.

Comment: There are [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities). You can find many answers for this question, by the way.

Comment: Other than a strict "No", and a more general, but incomplete: "For the APIs which both implement, they are largely compatible", what are you actually asking, *exactly*? What are you wanting to get out of an answer? Note that asking us about the *future* is inherently opinion based (off-topic), even if a projection can be based on what's available/announced. If you want to ask the *current* state, that's something that can be covered as fact.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities). It highlights all the differences. I think in the future the differences will be minimal.

> Extensions built with WebExtension APIs are designed to be compatible
>   with Chrome and Opera extensions: as far as possible, extensions
>   written for those browsers should run on Firefox with minimal changes.